# Navbar fade In when back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying this jQuery example

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

  // hide .navbar first
 // $(".masthead").hide();
  $(".masthead").css("background-color","inherit");
  // fade in .navbar
  $(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
            // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $('.masthead').fadeIn();
        $(".masthead").css("background-color","black");
      } else if($(this).scrollTop === 0){
                $('.masthead').fadeIn();

      } else {
        $('.masthead').fadeOut();
      }
    });


  });

});
}(jQuery));
```

It shows the menu/navbar when I run the page and disapears when I start scrolling and after 700 pixels navbar is displayed again with black background, I expected it to fade in again after I come back to the top.

```
if($(this).scrollTop === 0){
    $('.masthead').fadeIn();
}
```

But it have not worked. How do scrollTop() work then? I have also tried to set scrollTop < 10, but with no success. How do I make it work when I'm back at 10 pixels or zero?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the function body to 0, not the actual results of the function (the scroll value), so this:

```
if($(this).scrollTop === 0){
    $('.masthead').fadeIn();
}
```

should become this:

```
if($(this).scrollTop() === 0){
    $('.masthead').fadeIn();
}
```

---

### TL;DR

It's `scrollTop` vs. `scrollTop()`.

Comment: This is somewhat confusing because in the Native DOM API, it actually would be `scrollTop` but jQuery is `scrollTop()`. Good catch.

Comment: @TinyGiant, thank you. Yeah, there are quite a few unfortunately named functions/methods in jQuery. However, OP had already used it properly in the first it condition.